# How do I count number of times that a command has ran and add if condition?

Tags: bash, shell

Basically I need to control how fast I upload files to AWS S3 - I have a folder with tens of thousands of files, and this is what I do now:

```
for f in *; do aws s3 cp $f s3://my-bucket; done;
```

What I'd like to do is like this pseudo code:

```
for f in *; 
   cnt=0
   do aws s3 cp $f s3://my-bucket
   if cnt % 1000 == 0
       sleep 5 min
done;
```

Sorry for mixing python and shell syntax together but I hope I expressed my idea clearly. Please kindly help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do what you want.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

counter=1

for f in *; do
  echo aws s3 cp "$f" s3://my-bucket
  ((counter++ % 10 == 0)) && echo && sleep 5
done
```

- That's just a dry-run of what should/could be executed.
- Remove the `echo` in front of `aws` and the `&& echo` if you think the output is ok.